Need some advice how to apply IV analysis to examine monetary aspect of the mundell-fleming model
We are planning to use instrumental variable analysis to examine the monetary mechanism of the Mundell-Fleming model in our country. Our dependent variable is real GDP per capita with domestic liquidity (real money supply) as our independent variable. We posit that the real capital account (a portion of the BOP) as an endogeneous variable, and real exchange rate is the instrumental variable that affects real GDP via real capital account.
However, the test shows that we have a weak instrument and the variables failed the test of endogeneity. It seems that IV is not the proper model, but it is the one adviced to us.
Any suggestion how to move forward given our circumstance? Also, to anyone who are quite familiar in this field, can you point us to some existing literature which we can work with? I will highly appreciate any of your response and suggestions. Thank you!
